# Best practices for formatting statements in python

Tags: python

Not a programming question per se, but important re writing clean programs in python:

Are there any best practices for leaving space between arguments to a function? E.g which is better:

1.

```
idf['datetime'] = pandas.to_datetime(idf['Year'].astype(str) + ' ' + idf['JD'].astype(str), format = '%Y %j')
```

or
2.

```
idf['datetime'] = pandas.to_datetime(idf['Year'].astype(str)+' '+idf['JD'].astype(str),format='%Y %j')
```

Also, what is better;

1.

```
idf['MONTH'] = idf['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
idf['DAY']   = idf['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
idf['unq']   = idf.groupby('Ob').cumcount() + 1
```

or 2.

```
idf['MONTH'] = idf['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
idf['DAY'] = idf['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
idf['unq'] = idf.groupby('Ob').cumcount() + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Achim PEP8 is a de facto guide, so applying that to your code:
Your first examples, option 1 but the lines are too long
Your second examples, the second option is preferred

To comply with PEP8 line length, you can change your first code to:

```
idf['datetime'] = pandas.to_datetime(idf['Year'].astype(str)
idf['datetime'] += ' ' + idf['JD'].astype(str), format = '%Y %j')
```

However, I would prefer:

```
idf['datetime'] = " ".join([pandas.to_datetime(idf['Year'].astype(str),
                            idf['JD'].astype(str), format = '%Y %j')])
```

[Note: I follow PEP8, with the one exception: I personally believe 80 is too short for line length and often change the check to 120]

Answer (score 7):

In Python you have very well defined and more or less as standard established formatting rules. Please have a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). There are tools to check the rules and integrations for the most common editors.

Comment: I use PyCharm and it does highlight PEP8 violations, however I do not find PEP8 compliant code to be the most readable...

Comment: You are of course allowed to disagree with most Python developers. ;-)